# System of ODEs causes NDSolve::nlnum1 warning

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using some amplitude and frequency with `NDSolve`, but I get some warnings which is included here.

I think my program is fine until before `SolAv`. But, I could not find why this warning appears. The code I used is included here

```
Clear[LΛ, f, c, cn, A, v, An, As, vs, Q0]
(*  *)
LΛ[f_] := (8 π ν ρ f)/ρ;
c = cn An/A[x, t];
Eq1 = Simplify[D[A[x, t], t] + D[A[x, t] v[x, t], x]];

Eq2 = Simplify[
   A[x, t] D[v[x, t], t] + A[x, t] v[x, t] D[v[x, t], x] + 
     c^2 D[A[x, t], x] + LΛ[v[x, t]] /. 
    R -> Sqrt[A[x, t]/π]];


A[x_, t_] = As[x]; v[x_, t_] = vs[x];
vs[x_] = Q0/As[x];
LE = Simplify[{Eq1, Eq2}];
Sols = DSolve[{LE[[2]] == 0, As[L] == An}, As[x], x];
Simplify[Sols]
Am = {1.1290263207533879`*^-7 - 7.473554942563208`*^-8 I, 
   3.9210392313242154`*^-7 - 
    5.198540412010037`*^-7 I, -3.666731498809855`*^-8 + 
    4.026529625379335`*^-7 I, 
   2.907927596300974`*^-7 + 
    6.688553949022083`*^-7 I, -5.901727476937829`*^-7 - 
    6.780384037260203`*^-7 I, -3.4029233536625084`*^-7 - 
    2.1769713736464412`*^-7 I, 
   5.06797091099388`*^-7 - 
    2.5532173494757542`*^-8 I, -5.4970528551404145`*^-9 - 
    7.182784241041546`*^-8 I, -3.491221569640317`*^-7 + 
    2.6310572644437936`*^-7 I, -1.1440129576533528`*^-8 - 
    1.7690933852144399`*^-7 I};

ffp = {2/7, 4/7, 6/7, 8/7, 10/7, 12/7, 2, 16/7, 18/7, 20/7};
Clear[LΛ, f, c, cn, A, v, An, As, vs, Asf, vsf, Q0, \
ω, R, ν, ρ, EqIC, Qap, δ, vao, Aap]
AmpQ1 = {};
AmpQ2 = {};
TU = {};
TV = {};
TP = {};
TQ = {};
Print["Start"]
Table[
  cn = 111 ;(*m/s*)
  R0 = 4 10^-3; (*m*)
  Q0 = 2.03 /1000/60; (*m^3/s*)
  μ = 0.0147  ; (*pa-s*)
  ρ = 1167;(*kg/m^3*)
  ν = μ/ρ;
  L = 10;
  δ = 0.01;
  An = π R0^2;
  (*Tp=0.2;ω=2 π 1/Tp;*)
  ω = 2 π  ffp[[f]];
  (*Print["Disharge fluctuation=",δ Q0];*)
  
  M10C =
   1 - 2 BesselJ[
       1, α I^(3/2)]/(α I^(3/2)
         BesselJ[0, α I^(3/2)] );
  Par[α_] = I π μ α^2 (M10C^-1 - 1);
  G[x_] = 
   Par[α] /. α -> Sqrt[A[x, t] ω/(π*ν)];
  (*LΛ[f_]:=(8 π ν ρ f)/ρ;*)
  τ[x_, t_] = G[x]   v[x, t]/ρ;
  
  (*LΛ[f_]:=(8 π ν ρ f)/ρ;*)
  
  c = (cn An)/A[x, t];
  Eq1 = Simplify[D[A[x, t], t] + D[A[x, t] v[x, t], x]];
  
  Eq2 = Simplify[
    A[x, t] D[v[x, t], t] + A[x, t] v[x, t] D[v[x, t], x] + 
     c^2 D[A[x, t], x] + τ[x, t](*LΛ[v[x,
    t]]/.R\[Rule]Sqrt[A[x,t]/π]*)];
  
  A[x_, t_] = As[x] + ϵ Asf[x] E^(I ω t);
  v[x_, t_] = vs[x] + ϵ vsf[x] E^(I ω t);
  LEq = Series[{Eq1, Eq2}, {ϵ, 0, 1}] // Normal;
  EqIC = Coefficient[LEq, ϵ] /. t -> 0;
  (* steady flow solution *)
  As[x_] = 
   An E^(-((8 π Q0 (L - x) ν)/(-An^2 cn^2 + Q0^2)));(*As[x_]=
  An \[ExponentialE]^((7 π Q0 (L-x))/(12500 (An^2 cn^2-Q0^2)));*)
  
  vs[x_] = Q0/As[x];
  
  solAv = 
   First@NDSolve[
     Evaluate[{EqIC[[1]] == 0, EqIC[[2]] == 0, 
       Asf[L] == (- cn/I ω)  Derivative[1][Asf][L] (*Asf[L]*), 
       Asf[0] vs[0] + As[0] vsf[0] == Am [[f]] }], {Asf[
       x], vsf[x]}, {x, 0, L}];
  
  , {f, 1, Length[ffp]}];
Print["finish"];
```

The code causes the warning

> NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value `{(0. +0. I)-444/7 I π Asf'[10],-1.12903*10^-7+7.47355*10^-8 I}` is not a list of numbers with dimensions `{2}` when the arguments are `{0. +0. I,0. +0. I,0. +0. I,0. +0. I}`.
>
> ...

If you help me to resolve the problem, it will be helpful for me.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What do you try to solve? Could you show your system in Latex form?

Comment: In addition to what @AlexTrounev said would be very helpful, can you explain why you decided to undo my edits? I just wrote the Greek characters nicely to make your post readable.

Comment: Please make some effort in creating a minimal working example: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871

Comment: Looking at your error it seems some function called Asf is not being assigned numerical values, whereas NDSolve needs numerical values as input

Comment: You have the function `Asf[x]` undefined in your code. It first appears in the definition of `A[x_, t_] `, but is itself never defined.

Comment: (Rollback to Revision 5) The seemingly simplified sample is worse than the original messy sample, it's full of mistakes, and doesn't reproduce the mentioned warning at all.

Comment: (Rollback to Revision 5) Once again, the seemingly simplified sample is worse than the original messy sample, it involves simple mistake, and doesn't reproduce the mentioned warning at all.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I'd like to emphasize again, you should put some effort in creating a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871). Anyway, the underlying issue of the messy sample turns out to be worth discussing, so let me give an answer.

The sample can be boiled down to the following single line:

```
NDSolve[{g'[x] == 0, g[0] == 0, f'[x] + f[x] == 0, f'[1] == 0}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value `{0.,f'[1]}` is not a list of numbers with dimensions `{2}` when the arguments are `{0.,0.,0.,0.}`.

```
(* Input returned *)
```

Further check suggests this warning is caused by `"Shooting"` method:

```
NDSolve[{g'[x] == 0, g[0] == 0, f'[x] + f[x] == 0, f'[1] == 1234}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {g[1] == 2345}}]
```

> NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value `{2345., - 1234 + f'[1]}` is not a list of numbers with dimensions `{2}` when the arguments are `{2.71828, 2345., 1., 2345.}`.

```
(* Input returned *)
```

It's not clear to me how `"Shooting"` method parses the system, but it's clear to me `"Shooting"` method is having difficulty in handling the boundary condition `f'[1] == 1234`.

This isn't too surprising. Clearly, b.c. involving 1st order derivatvie is unusual for 1st order ODE: in cases like `{f'[x] == x, f'[1] == 0}` the solution won't even be uniquely determined!

"OK, but in our case the system happens to be well-determined, how to make `NDSolve` correctly parse the b.c.?" One possible way is to transform the unusual b.c. to a usual one: from `f'[x] + f[x] == 0, f'[1] == 0` we can easily deduce `f[1] == 0`, so:

```
NDSolve[{g'[x] == 0, g[0] == 0, f'[x] + f[x] == 0, f[1] == 0}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

And this method is perfectly suitable for your original problem:

```
…
newbc = Eliminate[{EqIC[[1]] == 0, EqIC[[2]] == 0, 
                   Asf[L] == (-cn/I ω) Asf'[L]} /. x -> L, 
                  {Asf'[L], vsf'[L]}];

solAv = First@
  NDSolve[{EqIC[[1]] == 0, EqIC[[2]] == 0, newbc, 
     Asf[0] vs[0] + As[0] vsf[0] == Am[[f]]}, {Asf[x], vsf[x]}, {x, 0, L}]
…
```

Comment: that's a wonderful and very pedagogical answer!

Comment: Thank you so much now the program is run.